# the condition has length > 1 in if(nrow(.) > 0) after pipe

Tags: r, if-statement, pipe

I switched my coding to pipe usage and encounter difficulties. In the current case I have a dataframe `df` that is processed in some way and then a function is applied to the resulting dataframe. Something like this:

```
library(magrittr)
# Create data.
df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b= -10:-1)
# Process data.
df %>% 
  {.$c <- rowSums(.); .} %>%
# Keep only relevant rows
  .[.$c > 11, , drop= FALSE] %>%
# Go on if there are rows left...
  if(nrow(.) > 0){
    print("here is my code")
  } else{
    print("here is my code b")
  }
```

Runing this gives me `Error in if (.) nrow(.) > 0 else { : the condition has length > 1`. Here, I want my code b to tun. How to adapt the code to make it work?

**EDIT**

To sum up the answers: It is not recommended to use the pipe with `if(...){...}`, and if you nonetheless do so, your code becomes clumsy. To me, this points to the limitations of the pipe.

Comment: wrap the if call in `{}` and it should work, but these are not calls that one would usually pipe, this code would look better without pipes or at least using transform() and subset(), or in the tidyverse mutate(), filter(), and when()

Comment: @moodymudskipper Tried `{}` inside if but did not work or I do it the wrong way. I do not want to store the temporary result of this whole transformation of my dataframe as an object and would rather use the pipe. I see no abvious way to use the functions suggested in my big code inside the if statement...

Comment: fair enough let me answer properly

Comment: don't pipe from your subset to the if statement

Comment: You have to wrap the whole `if` in `{}`: `{if ... }}`. This solves the problem ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `if` like so

```
df %>% 
  {.$c <- rowSums(.); .} %>%
  .[.$c > 11, , drop= FALSE] %>%
  {`if`(nrow(.) == 0, print("here is my code"), print("here is my code b"))}
```

Or slightly more hackish

```
df %>% 
  {.$c <- rowSums(.); .} %>%
  .[.$c > 11, , drop= FALSE] %>%
  nrow() %>% 
  `if`(print("here is my code b"), print("here is my code"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't pipe from the subsetting of your data to the if statement. make a new data.frame and pass it to the if statments

```
library(magrittr)
# Create data.
df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b= -10:-1)
# Process data.
df2 <- df %>% 
  {.$c <- rowSums(.); .} %>%
  # Keep only relevant rows
  .[.$c > 11, , drop= FALSE] 
  # Go on with code a if there are rows left...
  if(nrow(df2) > 0){
    print("here is my code")
    # Code b if there are no rows..
  } else{
    print("here is my code b")
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You might fix your code by wrapping with an extra `{}`, this forces the dots to be used explicitly

```
library(magrittr)
# Create data.
df <- data.frame(a=1:10, b= -10:-1)
# Process data.
df %>% 
  {.$c <- rowSums(.); .} %>%
  # Keep only relevant rows
  .[.$c > 11, , drop= FALSE] %>%
  # Go on if there are rows left...
  {if(nrow(.) > 0){
    print("here is my code")
  } else{
    print("here is my code b")
  }}
#> [1] "here is my code b"
```

The reason it worked as it did is that `if` is a 3 arg function, receiving the condition, the yes action and the no action (futher args are ignored)

Here you're pushing a dot into the first arg, so the code it tries to run is
`if(.) nrow(.)>0 else print("here is my code")` where `.` is the outut from previous steps (a data frame and not a boolean)

This is very weird code though, an idiomatic piped call would look more like (still with the weird piped if, to avoid a temp variable creation):

```
df %>% 
  transform(c = rowSums(.)) %>% 
  subset(c > 11) %>% 
  {if(nrow(.) > 0){
    print("here is my code")
  } else {
    print("here is my code b")
  }}
#> [1] "here is my code b"

# or the following not to use the braces, closer to Cett's solution
df %>% 
  transform(c = rowSums(.)) %>% 
  subset(c > 11) %>% 
  nrow() %>%
  if (.) {
    print("here is my code")
  } else {
    print("here is my code b")
  }
#> [1] "here is my code b"
```

With the tidyverse the first step would be:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>% 
  mutate(c = rowSums(.)) %>% 
  filter(c > 11) %>% 
  ...
```

If you want to keep your syntax but not populate your environment with temp variables you can use `local()`

```
local({
  df$c <- rowSums(df)
  df <- df[df$c > 11, , drop= FALSE]
  if(nrow(df) > 0){
    print("here is my code")
  } else{
    print("here is my code b")
  }
})
#> [1] "here is my code b"
# df was not modified in your global environment
nrow(df)
#> [1] 10
```

Usually if you have complex code, with a lot of variables created, you should work with functions simple enough so that their execution environment never contains all that many variables so you wouldn't need `local()` for housekeeping.

Comment: Why do `if(nrow(df))` yet `df` was never modified in the first code?

Comment: Runing solution two gives me "here is my code" and not "here is my code b". This is because there was no assigment to `df`. And indeed I do not want to overwrite df with the processed version..

Comment: right, sorry, my oversight, then we'll have to pipe the if. Corrected now. But really, this is not the right way. Use local, or a function, or a different variable (that you might rm() once unneeded if populating the execution environment is such an issue)

Comment: Thanks. `nrow() %>%` doesn't work for me because `.` needs to stay the processed `df` for the code inside the if conditions. Anyway, I've learnt that pipes have limitations and should not be used with if statements. Too bad

Comment: Then you can use `purrr:: when()`, see the examples at the bottom of https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/when.html . It was deprecated though and it is recommended to use `if` outside of the pipe.

Comment: Or use the nakedpipe and you can use if : https://github.com/moodymudskipper/nakedpipe